# Constraints(Time/area..) in Yosys and/or ABC

Tags: constraints, yosys, berkeley-abc

I am using the following basic script to synthesize simple adder design

```
# read design
read_verilog fulladder1.v
hierarchy -check

# high-level synthesis
proc; opt; fsm; opt; memory; opt

# low-level synthesis
techmap; opt

# map to target architecture
abc -g AND,XOR

# split larger signals
splitnets -ports; opt

show
```

With using

```
abc -g AND,XOR
```

command, ABC syhthesis the design just using AND,XOR and NOT (NOT is automatically added) gates.

My questions about this issue are;

1) Is there any way to force YOSYS and/or ABC tools to use just one universal gate (e.g. NAND) for whole design?

&

After using

```
abc -g AND,XOR
```

like command.

2) Is there a way to reduce or maximize the number of specified gates(e.g.XOR)  by adding constraints (time/area/priority?...) to libraries

or

using special YOSYS and/or ABC  commands?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The "cost" of built-in cell types is hardcoded in `kernel/cost.h`.

When mapping to a custom cell library you can specify the cost (area) in your liberty file. See `examples/cmos/cmos_cells.lib` for an example.

ABC needs a NOT gate in the cell library. But you can always map to a cell library of e.g. NAND and NOT and then use the `techmap` command to replace all instances of NOT with a NAND with both inputs driven by the same signal (or one input driven by constant 1, whatever you prefer).

---

**Edit:** Mapping NOT to NAND with techmap is easy. Simply create a file named `not2nand.v` with the following contents:

```
module \$_NOT_ (input A, output Y);
  \$_NAND_ _TECHMAP_REPLACE_ (.A(A), .B(A), .Y(Y));
endmodule
```

Then you can map NOT gates to NANDs using `techmap -map not2nand.v`.

Comment: Hi @Clifford, thanks to your answer, I can add area contstraints and change  the number of specified cells in design . But I can't manage to replace "NOT cells" with the "NAND cells". I am very new user for yosys and I have tried "techmap" and also "setparam" commands but I can't find simple example about what to do step by step and where to insert this commands in my script file.. Could you please guide me and/or share some simple examples ? Thank you